# Removing focus from default date in CalendarView

Tags: android, xamarin

When creating a CalendarView, the current date is automatically selected:

[image]

My layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <CalendarView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/createReservationCalendarView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The code:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.CreateReservationCalendar);

    var calendar = FindViewById<CalendarView>(Resource.Id.createReservationCalendarView);
    calendar.MinDate = DateTimeConverter(DateTime.Now);
    calendar.MaxDate = DateTimeConverter(DateTime.Now.AddDays(14));

    calendar.DateChange += (s, e) =>
    {
        var myReservations = new Intent(this, typeof(CreateReservation));
        StartActivity(myReservations);
    };  
}
```

This means that if the user taps the current date, the click handler does not get executed. What I would like is for the user to be able to click on any of the dates and be directed to the next screen.

How do I remove the focus from the default date?

While we are at it, I have a side question. The current date range is 14 days, and it spans from December to January. The title of the CalendarView is January, even though a date in December is selected. Is there any way to change the title?

Comment: I have tried the CalendarView in Android 6.0, I can tap the current data and the datachange handler get executed. And the Title is December.

Comment: Did you try it with MinDate and MaxDate that spans over two months? I am running 6.0 as well, and I cant select the current date, because it is already selected. Can I see your code? Thx.

Comment: I am sorry. My emulator was running android 4.4. You are right. The UI is way nice now aswell. Thanks.

Comment: @Kenci, Did you found answer ?